# Fetch tweets for a specific Twitter user?

Tags: delphi, twitter, delphi-2009

What is the protocol of getting the tweets of a user from Twitter?

Let's say I want to write a program that follows a Twitter account and read all its tweets. What is the protocol that needs to be implemented in order to fetch the entries of a Twitter user.

edit:
i found this:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/show

what is "slug" ?

Comment: That resource is not for getting tweets. Instead it is for getting information about a specific Twitter list. A slug is the "friendly" or human readable name of the resource. For example, in `http://some.url.com/57/here-is-the-slug`, you can differentiate the ID of the resource (57) from the slug (here-is-the-slug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twitter API is a RESTful HTTP API. The only protocol involved is HTTP. The payload is most commonly JSON. You can read about the entire RESTful API here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

For your purposes, you would need to use the [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) resource. You can specify which user to retrieve by using the `screen_name` parameter.